# React .js TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

There is a user object i created in `App.js` however when I try to access its property in my `Person` component it gives me the error.

```
class ParentApp extends Component {
  render() {
    var user = {
      name: "syedhnajamnaqvi",
      hobbies: ["xbox", "swimming"]
    };

    return <div>{/* ... */}</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very little information you've provided to us. Please share your components so we can see what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access `name` inside the Person component using `this.props.user.name` if you do this:

```
class ParentApp extends Component {
  render() {
    var user = {
      name: "syedhnajamnaqvi",
      hobbies: ["xbox", "swimming"]
    };

    return <Person user={user}>;
  }
}
```